# Training changing input size RNN on Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I want to train an RNN with different input size of sentence X, without padding. The logic used for this is that I am using Global Variables and for every step, I take an example, write the forward propagation i.e. build the graph, run the optimizer and then repeat the step again with another example. The program is extremely slow as compared to the numpy implementation of the same thing where I have implemented forward and backward propagation and using the same logic as above. The numpy implementation takes a few seconds while Tensorflow is extremely slow. Can running the same thing on GPU will be useful or I am doing some logical mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

As a general guideline, GPU boosts performance only if you have calculation intensive code and little data transfer. In other words, if you train your model one instance at a time (or on small batch sizes) the overhead for data transfer to/from GPU can even make your code run slower! But if you feed in a good chunk of samples, then GPU will definitely boost your code.

Comment: The code becomes even more slower when I add an extra session.run() statement to print some values during the training process.

Comment: You might want to use `FileWriter` and `TensorBoard` to get outputs with minimal impact on performance.